# If value does not match in a cell then show it in another cell

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a Google Sheet in which there are multiple codes. In one cell there is more than one code and in the other cell, the decision selected by the user is followed by the code.

Responses are fixed for the given codes.

I want the sheet to show if the codes selected by the users are wrong or correct in another column (if correct then leave the cell blank else to show the code selected by the user i.e the wrong code).

The conditions are:

**Case 1**: if the code displayed in column A is either "P" or "W" then the user's decision (column B)  should be either "NO" or "YES" and the code (column C) selected by the user should be either "N" (if the decision is "NO") or "R" (if the decision is "YES") then in column D if the decision and code matches then leave the cell blank else to show the wrong code selected by the user.

**Case 2**: if the code displayed in column A does not have "P" or "W" code in the cell then the user's decision (column B) should be "NO" and the code (column C) selected by the user should be "IM" then in column D if the decision and code matches then leave the cell blank else to show the wrong code selected by the user. (P.S.: this condition can be created in another column).

[image]

I'm sharing a screenshot for reference. I searched for a formula but nothing worked.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try:

```
=indeX(lambda(regX,if(len(A2:A),
                               IF((regX*(B2:B="NO")*(C2:C="N"))+
                                  (regX*(B2:B="YES")*(C2:C="R"))+
                                  (not(regX)*(B2:B="NO")*(C2:C="IM")),,C2:C),))
      (regexmatch(A2:A,"\b(P|W)\b")))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much @rockinfreakshow. It worked like a charm. Could you please share the explanation of this formula as to how it works?

Comment: well first step is to check and see if there's `P` or `W` in 1st column using regex expression and its used in the IF ELSE part. the 3 IF ELSE statements used are pretty much straightforward as they exactly mirror the conditions you described in your question. `*` used in the formula is `AND` condition & `+` used is the `OR` condition

Comment: Thank you for your response. what about the "b" in the last line? ""\b(P|W)\b""

Comment: just making sure `P` and `W` letters are stand-alone & somehow not part of some words like `AP` or `AWS` and so on... `\b` is the line break condition check used within regex

Comment: How can I use only this line in another column ? "not(regX)*(M2:M="NO")*(N2:N="IM")),,N2:N),))".  (Condition 2)

Comment: Is there any way to add 3rd condition in the formula "if the code displayed in column A does not have "P" or "W" code in the cell then the user's decision (column B) should be "NO" and the code (column C) selected by the user should be "IM" then in column D if the decision and code matches then leave the cell blank ( blank only if in column F has a code "O") else show the wrong code selected by the user. In this Formula,=indeX(lambda(regX,if(len(A2:A),IF((regX*(B2:B="NO")*(C2:C="N"))+
(regX*(B2:B="YES")*(C2:C="R"))+(not(regX)*(B2:B="NO")*(C2:C="IM")),,C2:C),))
(regexmatch(A2:A,"\b(P|W)\b")))

Comment: it would help if you could share a sample sheet with demo data and expected output manually entered so that it gives a clear picture for us to work on...